# Scraping html tables in .NET and taking care of colspans

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing, html-table

I am trying  to scrape HTML tables in my .NET application, however I came across tables that are aggressively using colspan and rowspan attributes on cells causing me headache. I was wondering if there is a library available that can convert a table into an array of strings and taking care of colspan e.g if colspan=5 on a TD element then it will use the value of the TD for the next 5 elements

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=4>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr></table>
```

the output would be an array of the following:

[1,2,3,4,5]
  [1,1,1,1,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be able to use `ParseControl`, which would make the whole thing fairly trivial, since you can access the Colspan property.

Comment: I can do the parsing with no problem and can access the properties as well. What I need is some kind of logic that would fill up the missing cells with values so the resulting array will be rectangular

Comment: @gyurisc, ah ok. can you not just read the colspan, and add x number of 1's to the 'row list'? ie, if not present, 1, otherwise value. eg `rowList.AddRange(System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat(cellValue,cellColspan))`

Comment: This is what I am trying to do. Trying to handle the rowpsans and colspan, but I thought that there are already ready-made solutions perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a XmlDocument and then loop through it. Not sure if that's the best solution, but it works.
Maybe LINQ to XML?